# How to divide fabricJS canvas programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

This question belongs to fabricJS and canvas. I need to divide canvas in several ways programmatically (Eg: 1 into 2, 1 into 3). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi isuru, Can you provide design samples.?

Comment: Your question is very unclear! :-o I guess you could create 2 Fabric.Rects -- one covering the left side and the other covering the right side.

Comment: @Mullainathan please check layouts in following link. https://www.casetify.com/design/iphone6s/new-standard

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Actually I want to know is there any way to do this in fabricJS.

Comment: @isuru Your question is not clear. It lacks important details. You should read the guide that I have provided a link for, and find the important details that you need to include. Read over the guide and improve your question so that it is an acceptable question and so that we can help you.

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you are asking but one way to achieve the effect you are looking for is using [groups](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3#groups).

Instead of having two canvas or trying to divide a canvas into two rects etc, you can have two groups, arrange the objects within each group using a relative offset to the group, and arrange the groups relative to canvas.

I'll add a fiddle when I have more time, but that's the principle.